# Http Post a Stream in F# without reading into a Byte Array

Tags: f#, dotnet-httpclient, c#-to-f#, f#-data

With C# I can use the `System.Net.Http` Library to post a stream directly like so:

```cs
private async Task UploadFileAsync(Uri uri, string filename)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        await client.PostAsync(uri, new StreamContent(stream));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in F# in a functionally idiomatic way?

`FSharp.Data.Http.Request` lets you post Binary data but requires a byte array to do so, which means reading the stream into memory. I'd like to avoid this as I am posting > 20Mb.

Comment: What's stopping you from using `HttpClient` in F#?

Comment: Nothing really, just want to know if this is catered for in lib targeted for FSharp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing this in a *functionally idiomatic* way would involve some kind of IO monad. As F# is a mixed paradigm language e.g.

```
let uploadFile (uri: Uri) fileName =
    async {
        use stream = File.OpenRead fileName
        use client = new HttpClient()
        return! client.PostAsync(uri, new StreamContent(stream)) |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
```

is perfectly acceptable IMHO.

Comment: Agreed. But seeing as I am already using the FSharp.Data library I want to know if I can avoid bringing in the System.Net.Http namespace, too. Plus I'm not even 100% sure that the HttpClient isn't copying the stream into a byte array internally!

Comment: "*But seeing as I am already using the FSharp.Data library I want to know if I can avoid bringing in the System.Net.Http namespace, too.*" How on earth is this a concern?

Comment: Because then I'll be using two Http libs in the same system and it won't be obvious why. Smelly.